# Сброс stdin eof

Tags: c

По задачи нужно добавить элементы в таблицу и потом удалить из таблицы элемент указав его по имени.

```
#define MAXWORD 100

int main () {
   char name[MAXWORD];
   char defn[MAXWORD];

   ...

   while (getword(name, MAXWORD) != EOF) {
       getword(name, MAXWORD);

       ...
       // Создаем таблицу и добавляем туда введенные значения.
       ...

    }

    // Вводим имя таблицы которую нужно удалить.
    getword(name, MAXWORD);
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Функция getword(char *arg1, arg2) выполняет чтение клавиатуры по символьно добавляет их в arg1. В arg2 хранится размер arg1. Как только с клавиатубы будет введен пробел или перевод строки и т.п. функция перестает считывать входные значения и возвращает первый символ.

Третья функция getword завершается  сразу, даже не успев что либо принять. Как я понимаю из-за того что использую в цикле EOF, Как можно сбросить его? Пробовал использовать стандартные средства, результат тотже (Я ввожу несколько значений добавляя их в таблицу, завершаю заполнение с помошью сигнала EOF (ctr+D),программа проходит оставшийся код и завершается).

Comment: Функция `clearerr()`.

Comment: @eanmos  Да, получилось. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрел ferror(stdin), флаг ошибки равен нулю. Непонятно как clearerr решает проблемму.

Comment: `clearerr` сбрасывает не только индикатор ошибки (`error`), но и индикатор конца файла (`eof`). См. ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сбросить индикатор конца файла можно воспользоваться стандартной функцией [`clearerr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/clearerr/). Кроме сброса индикатора `eof`, функция также сбрасывает индикатор ошибки.